# How do I change the default CSS settings in Internet Explorer 9?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a terminal server that has IE 9 installed.  It is not used to surf the web, but to look at html files on the server and by an application.  The application we use on this server calls browser windows to display configurable html strings in message boxes and the like.

You can't make the application use a particular css stylesheet.  It simply uses the browser defaults to render the html strings.  How do I change the default style the browser is using so the html strings are rendered in a more desirable fashion???

Comment: Tools > Internet Options > General Tab > Accessibility button under "Appearance" > Choose your own StyleSheet.css file ?

Comment: Nice idea, but that only seems to work for the user that configures it, not the 100 other users that remote to the server to use that application.  We have some clients running that application on IE 10 which has different defaults and I am trying to get a more consistent look between the clients and terminal server access.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't know the set-up of how the application was accessed. I guess it would only work that way if the application ran on the browser installed on the server itself, and people remoted in under the same account. In that case, I would say just put the CSS styles in the `<head>` tags of the HTML. That will override the default styles of the browser.

Comment: Ouch. The strings are typically like "<h2>Warning! Your password is about to expire.</h2>"  And they are scattered around a bunch of different places in the configuration code.  It would not be fun to go edit them all with "<head> .... </head>" I guess you are saying that the actual defaults are buried in the registry and difficult or dangerous to muck with?  I have been googling all day, and all I get is Css Reset advice and other things pertinent to building a website.

Comment: I mean place all your CSS in the `<head>` tag. You can be as filtered and specific there as you can with an external stylesheet. e.g. `h2 {font-weight: bold; color: red}` or `div h2:last-of-type {}` etc. I don't know for sure, but I bet the CSS styles for IE are probably in the registry. I'll try to flag down an IE dev to ask.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that there IS NO <head> tag.  It isn't a website as such, but dozens of HTML strings scattered around a bunch of configuration code.  Imagine writing a few thousand VBA macros in Excel with html strings contained in variables to be called for use in displayed messages and forms. (msgBox("<h1>STOP You Idiot!!!</h1>"))  VBA has tools to make that use of html a questionable practice, but the application we are using is not Excel and the tools we have available are limited.  Thanks for your input though.  I can't find anything even in the registry.

Comment: Oh Jeez, I see now. That does sound like a nightmare then. Only a handful of settings are listed in the registry (
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Settings) and (
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main) that might differ from the default W3C values.